# Perl: Filesearch error

Tags: perl

Code:

```
$PATTERN = 'specialname';
my $ArchiveX = Archive::Zip->new();
$ArchiveX->writeToFileNamed($PATTERN.".zip");

    my $FileName = $File::Find::name;
    $FileName =~ s/\//\\/g;

    if ($FileName =~ /$PATTERN/) {
        print "Addfile:".$FileName;
        print "\n";
        $ArchiveX->addFile($FileName);
    }
```

Error:

> Can't call method "addFile" on an undefined value.
>   Can't call method "desiredCompressionLevel" on an undefined value

Comment: After the second line, add in a `die "crud, \$ArchiveX is not defined" unless defined $ArchiveX;` and see if it dies there.

Comment: It dies. And $ArchiveX is not defined

Comment: In that case, you need to find out why you're not able to assign to `$ArchiveX` a new `Archive::Zip` object.  You *are* using `strict` and `warnings`, right?

Comment: Can't opendir(D:\$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-339270556-673599523-3524176310-1006): Invalid argument
 at filename.pl line 68
Can't call method "desiredCompressionLevel" on an undefined value

Comment: There you go, you can't open a particular directory.  If it exists, get permission to open it.  If it doesn't exist, then either create it and move on or do something else.

Comment: @JackManey: consider converting your comments into an answer that could be accepted by the questioner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is built out of the comment thread in the question above.

First, determine if `$ArchiveX` is defined or not by adding

```
die "crud, \$ArchiveX is not defined" unless defined $ArchiveX;
```

just below the line where you initialize `$ArchiveX`.  If it's not defined (which is likely the case given your error message), then see what other warnings are thrown before the script `die`s.

You mentioned the error messages:

```
Can't opendir(D:\$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-339270556-673599523-3524176310-1006): Invalid argument at filename.pl line 68 Can't call method "desiredCompressionLevel" on an undefined value
```

That would seem to indicate that you can't open a directory.  Make sure the given directory exists.  If it doesn't, create it in your script.  If it does, make sure you have the relevant permissions to access it (and if you don't, get them).